# Heroku Deployment Failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Ok, so I've been at this for a little over a day now and would love to put this issue to bed. I'm doing the Hartl tutorial, Ruby on Rails Tutorial, and am at the end of chapter 1 trying to deploy my code to heroku.

- I have looked at message boards on stackoverflow and have seen quite a bit about private/public keys so I entered: ssh-keygen -t rsa and it did indeed generate a public/private key pair.. it tells me where the ID and public key have been saved and gives me the whole key fingerprint. Ok, good. So what's the issue?
- The issue is that I've gone through the "heroku login, heroku create, git push heroku master" steps a few times and always, *always*, end up with the same thing which is "The authenticity of host 'heroku.com (50.19.85.154)' can't be established.
  RSA key fingerprint is 8b:48:5e:67:0e:c9:16:47:32:f2:87:0c:1f:c8:60:ad.
  Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?"  <-- I always hit "no" because I don't know if it's cool/safe to hit "yes"
- What do you think I should do? (btw, I'm working in OS X)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to say yes! and have you uploaded your keys to heroku as that will be your next problem

```
heroku keys:add
```

Comment: Nathan - you're a champ. Appreciate your help. I'm sure I'll come across another stumbling block in no time as I'm new to this but for now, I've cleared this hurdle. THANK YOU!